# Java, string matching for validating permissions

Tags: java, regex, string, validation

Hi i'm working on an algorithm for validating permissions,
a permission is defined by a succession of token concatenated by a period,
for example:

```
this.is.a.permission
a.b.c.d
another.permission
```

permission can also contains special tokens listed below:

---

**Asterisk:**

```
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "this.is.*") // <-- return true
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "*") // <-- return true
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "random.*") // <-- return false
```

> The asterisk validate only his token and all the next

**Question Mark:**

```
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "this.is.?.permission") // <-- return true
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "?.is.a.permission") // <-- return true
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "this.?.wrong") // <-- return false
```

> The question mark validate only his token

**Inclusive List:**

```
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "this.is.[a,permission,c].permission")            // <-- return true
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "[this].is.a.[a,permission,c]")                       // <-- return true
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "this.[is,c,d].wrong")                                    // <-- return false
```

> The inclusive list validate token only if it's contained in itself, defined by [argument,argument1,argument2,...]

**Exclusive List:**

```
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "this.is.<b,c,d>.permission") // <-- return true
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "<everything>.is.a.<invalid>") // <-- return true
magicFunction("this.is.a.permission", "this.is.a.<permission,wrong>") // <-- return false
```

> The exclusive list validate token only if it's not contained in itself, defined by <argument,argument1,argument2,...>

---

Here is a test case:

```
public class PermissionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(rightPad("PERMISSION", 35) + rightPad("PERMISSION EXPRESSION", 35) + "RESULT");

        // ALL TRUE
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C",    "A.B.C.D");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.D",  "A.B.C.D");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.D",  "A.B.*");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.D",  "A.B.?.D");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.D",  "A.B.C.[D,E,F]");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.E",  "A.B.C.[D,E,F]");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.F",  "A.<A,C>.C.[D,E,F]");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.D",  "A.B.C.<A,B,C>");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.E",  "A.B.C.<A,B,C>");
        assert magicFunction(   "A.B.C.F",  "A.[B].C.<A,B,C>");

        System.out.println();

        // ALL FALSE
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C",    "A.B");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.D",  "A.B.?.E");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.D",  "A.D.*");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.D",  "A.B.?");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.Q",  "A.?.C.[D,E,F]");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.W",  "A.?.C.[D,E,F]");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.E",  "A.<B,D,E>.?.[D,E,F]");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.A",  "A.B.C.<A,B,C>");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.B",  "A.B.C.<A,B,C>");
        assert !magicFunction(  "A.B.C.C",  "A.[D].C.<A,B,C>");
    }

    public static boolean magicFunction(String permission, String permissionExpression) {
        boolean value = magicFunctionImplementation(permission, permissionExpression);
        System.out.println(
            rightPad(permissionExpression, 35) +
            rightPad(permission, 35) +
            value
        );
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * The function implementation
     * 
     * IMPLEMENT YOUR FUNCTION HERE
     */
    public static boolean magicFunctionImplementation(String permission, String permisionExpression) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * For formatting purpose
     */
    public static String rightPad(String pad, int size) {
        String paddedString = pad;
        for (int i = pad.length(); i < size; i++) {
            paddedString += " ";
        }
        return paddedString;
    }
}
```

Here is my final question is possible to write this function with a regular expression? if isn't possible there is a more elegant way to write this function?

Comment: This could be also a nice code-golf, feel free to post in the other forum

Comment: Have a look at my try - http://ideone.com/A7b0CN

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please answer with a post so i can give you the correct answer and some points?

Comment: Ok, looks like it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using

```
public static boolean magicFunctionImplementation(String permission, String permissionExpression) {
    boolean res = false;
    String rx = permissionExpression.replace(".", "\\.") // escape the dot in regex
            .replace("*", ".*") // prep the * token to match any 0+ chars
            .replace("?", ".")  // . will match any 1 char
            .replaceAll("\\[([^\\]\\[]*)]", "($1)") // [a,b] => (a|b) = match a or b
            .replaceAll("<([^<>]+)>", "(?:(?!$1)[^.])*") // <a,b> => (?:(?!a|b).)* = match text that is not a starting point of a or b
            .replace(",", "|"); // replace all commas with alternation symbol (for the above 2 patterns)
    if (permissionExpression.contains(permission)) { // if permissionExpr contains permission, it is TRUE
        res = true;
    } else {
        res = permission.matches(rx); // Check if the entire permission matches the regex
    }
    return res;
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/A7b0CN)

Comment: Could simplify to: `return permissionExpression.contains(permission) || permission.matches(rx)`